# How do you keep this dastardly bash script running in the background 24/7?

Tags: shell-script, jobs

This might sound like a duplicate, but hear me out first.

I run a shell script, which has a standard input active and sometimes on startup requires some input. I need for it to run 24/7 and it needs restart on failure by either inputting a command or just inputting "y" if the prompt pops up.
I've already tried two methods: using nohup and clicking Ctrl+Z, typing bg both show the job as stopped and it's not running. Only when I execute `fg` it goes active. Any clue how to solve this?

P.S I've also tried `scriptcommand &` it ends up with "Stopped" as well.

Would setting it up as a systemd service make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programs which rely on input as you described need to be started inside a terminal multiplexer like `tmux` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) or `screen` (https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). Think of it as a text-based version of a terminal window.

Use `screen my-program` to start `my-program`. Then you can *detach* from your virtual screen console using the key-stroke combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, and you're back to the shell where you started, but your program keeps running in the background.
Then, using `screen -r` you can reconnect to the virtual console.

screen (and your program) will keep running until you program exits or the server is rebooted.

`tmux` is quite similar, but has more options and features, and uses different keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

For the script to continue running in the background, use nohup: `nohup scriptcommand &`. Ideally, the script would have option to not prompt for input. If that isn't an option for some reason, [Expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) can be used to input 'y'.

Creating a systemd service for the script would allow for the script to be started on system reboot. You can also use `Restart=always` in your systemd file to restart the service if the service is exited or killed, the [systemd documentation has more info](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=).

Comment: The nohup method fails.

Comment: Do you have an error message? Or can you provide a better description?

Comment: I get the same Stopped message. I also already wrote in the question that I've tried it.

Comment: Saying you got a "Stopped" message doesn't provide enough info to debug the problem. Check `nohup.out` to debug further. Best guess, the something is being run which requires interaction, which is where nohup would usually have a problem.

Comment: That seems to be the case.